# Compilar Jar sin librerías externas incluidas

Tags: java, librería, jar, ant

Necesito compilar mi proyecto en Java a un `.jar` mediante un script ANT, pero quisiera que este no tome en cuenta las librerías externas porque me queda muy pesado; sino que estas queden en una carpeta externa al jar, por ejemplo en la carpeta `dist/lib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la solución. Cada proyecto java tiene un archivo llamado `build.xml` allí hay un tag de la siguiente manera: `<zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>` que le indica al compilador que compile todas la librerías.

Entonces comentando esa linea se genera un jar sin librerías (menos pesado). Ahora, para que funcione correctamente debe estar acompañado de la carpeta ***lib*** en donde se encuentran todos los jars de las librerías usadas en el proyecto.

Comment: Considera aceptar tu propia respuesta, se ve bastante buena.

Answer (score -3):

Lo que tu estas buscando se llama "FatJar" (jar gordo) es una version compilada de java con todas las librerias externas, dependiendo de como estas haciendo tu projecto puedes:

- Usando un IDE (Netbeans x ejemplo): https://dzone.com/articles/how-build-fat-jar-using
- Usando un gestor de dependencias (Maven x ejemplo): https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/
- Usando la linea de comandos: https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-how-to-create-executable-fatjar-without-ide

Comment: Hola! no, por el contrario. Lo que quiero es compilar únicamente mi código y consumir las librerías de forma externa, es decir, que no se compilen en un solo .jar

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912), él no quiere un fat jar, sino un thin. Parte del prolema del ususario es que seguramente no sabe acerca de los scopes de las dependencias, además de que no está usando maven en ningún momento.